# Virtual memory problem: How many page table levels do we need to map all the system's virtual memory?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

Consider a 36-bit byte-addressable system with virtual memory. The system can have a maximum of 32 GB of physical memory installed, and the page size is 16 KB. each page table entry takes up 4 bytes of space. Each page table must fit within 4 pages of space. How many page table levels do we need to map all the system's virtual memory?

this was my original logic: 16kb / 4 b = 2^14 / 2^2 = 2^12
4 * 2^12 = 2^14 number of entries
2^22 number of virtual pages
ceil(22/14) = 2

2 levels

Comment: A sane design needs a PTE to include at least a present / invalid bit, and probably "dirty" and "accessed" bits to let an OS manage virtual memory paging to disk.  Usually bits for permissions like user vs. supervisor,  and write / exec bits.  (e.g. like x86 has: https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Directory).  So that uses some of the 32 bits in a PTE, leaving the rest to be 4-page aligned physical addresses of the next level of pages, I guess?  There are plenty of offset-in-page bits to borrow for that, and have some left over, so I guess 32-bit PTE width is workable, esp. with a large pg sz.

Comment: (The number of physical address bits in a PTE doesn't affect how many virtual bits each level of paging can translate, as long as there are enough for the lowest level PTE to reference any physical page frame, so 35 - 12 = 23 bits.  So that leaves 32-23 = 9 bits for permissions and stuff, so that's fine.)

Comment: Your logic of 2 levels looks reasonable to me; do you have any reason to think it's wrong?